# Enviar CR LF pela porta Serial c#

Tags: c#, .net, ascii, porta-serial

Estou me comunicando por Serial (`SerialPort`) com um dispositivo que necessita que eu envie os comandos **CR LF** no final de cada instrução para o dispositivo entender que foi enviada uma instrução para ele.

As instruções que devo enviar são todas em ASCII.

Sei que na tabela ASCII existem os comandos Line-Feed - Alimenta linha (10) e Carriage-Return - Retorno do carro (13).

A comunicação está funcionando perfeitamente, porém o dispositivo sempre me retorna comando inválido pois preciso enviar estes caracteres no final de cada instrução.

Como faço para escrever junto no `Port.Write` ou no `Port.WriteLine` no final de cada instrução estes caracteres em ASCII?

Comment: Seria escrever a string `"\r\n"`?

Comment: @bigown O dispositivo me envia pela porta COM "UNKNOW COMMAND"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para enviar os comandos CR (Carriage Return) e LF (Line Feed) junto com o comando seria apenas adicionar os comando `\r` e `\n` no final do comando dentro do metódo para enviar um comando pela porta COM.

```
string command = "myCommand";

port.write(string.format("{0}\r\n", command));
```

`\r\n` = **CR** + **LF** → É usado como caractere de nova linha no Windows